# How can I derive axis index from mouse click event?

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick

This Python 3.11 script displays two graphs (axes):

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onclick(event):
  print(event.inaxes)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(3.5, 2.5), layout="constrained")
axs[0].plot(np.random.rand(10))
axs[1].plot(np.random.rand(10))
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Clicking first on the left graph, then on the right one, produces:

```
Axes(0.102541,0.111557;0.385554x0.871775)
Axes(0.602541,0.111557;0.385554x0.871775)
```

I see the first of `Axes` properties changing depending on the graph I clicked on: `0.102541` for the left one and `0.602541` for the right one. What is this property's name? Is there a simple way to derive an index of `axs`, which was clicked on from the `event`?

Answer (score 1):

just saw your question on mpl-discord and thought I'll have a look :-)

Here's a bit of clarification on how this works:

- `event.inaxes` gives you the `Axes`-object that triggered the event
- The 4 values you see in the print output correspond to the position of the axes
  (`left`, `bottom`, `width`x`height`) in relative figure-coordinates)

If you want to get the index of the axes in your `axs` list, you can do it like this:

```py
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(3.5, 2.5), layout="constrained")
axs[0].plot(np.random.rand(10))
axs[1].plot(np.random.rand(10))

axs = axs.tolist()   # convert to list so we can use .index(...) to find elements
def onclick(event):
    if event.inaxes in axs:
        print(axs.index(event.inaxes))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

... and to answer the question *"what is this property's name*?

It's the lower left corner of the position!

```py
axs[0].get_position().x0
>>> 0.10289777777777778
```

```py
axs[1].get_position().x0
>>> 0.6028977777777779
```

Comment: Thank you. Array lookup is definitely a practical solution in lieu of a specific matplotlib function. Your solution can be simplified a bit as posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

List lookup solution offered by @raphael can be simplified by using the original `axs` NumPy array as is:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onclick(event):
  if (i := np.argwhere(axs == event.inaxes)).size:
    print(i[0, 0])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(3.5, 2.5), layout="constrained")
axs[0].plot(np.random.rand(10))
axs[1].plot(np.random.rand(10))
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following callback function to achieve this:

```py
nrows = 2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=nrows, layout="constrained")

def onclick(event):
    if ax := event.inaxes:
        print(f'axes:   {divmod(ax.figure.axes.index(ax), nrows)}\n'
              f'bounds: {ax._position.bounds}')

for index, ax in np.ndenumerate(axs):
    ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Comment: It works, but in case of 2D *axs*, e.g. *plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2)* it will print 0, 1, 2, 3, instead of [0, 0], [0, 1], etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the 2d case. Unfortunately the callback function now depends on a global variable, but there seems to be no way around (since the subplot layout is not saved by the figure) other than wrapping the callback definition in a class that carries the layout shape.